# open graph image is loading properly for some pages but not others

Tags: facebook-opengraph

This is the open graph image I want to load on all my pages shared on Facebook.  It is loading properly on some pages and on others it is choosing a random image from the page. Below is the OG URL.  I am using Drupal CMS for my site.  All the proper code seems in place.

http://www.vaeducationoxnard.com/sites/default/files/styles/square_thumbnail/public/Charter%20Square%20Logo.png

Comment: Can you post the og tags which are generated on the pages that work and those that don't? I've seen issues before with urls with spaces in them - is it possible the space isn't being url-encoded on some of your pages?

Answer (score 0):

This is because, facebook sends the whole new request to the url you are passing and because of this it gets the image from og:image in which you have passed the default image. To overcome this, try to aadd the image parameter in the url you are passing

Ex. your/url?imgToShare=

And in the main page from where you set the meta tags, add one condition

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['imgToShare'])
{
 <set the meta tags for image you want>
}
else
{
 <meta tag with the default image>
}
?>
```

This helped me.

Please comment if you have any doubts.